# how can I declare int in a DEF that is running in a loop without it overriding the int everytime?

Tags: python

I an trying to make a roullete simulator in python where i use a strategy that doubles the bet everytime it loses. Problem is I made a bet variable in the def, and everytime the loop runs the def it overrides the bet variable back to being 1

```
def Simulate():

    
    number = random.randint(0,14)

    Money = 65
    StartBet = 1
    bet = StartBet

    if(Money > 0):
        if 8 > number > 0 :
            Money = Money +  bet
            bet = StartBet
            print(Money)
        else: 
            Money = Money - bet
            bet = bet * 2
            print(Money)
            
Emulations = 1000

for x in range(Emulations):
    Simulate()
```

Comment: Declare the variable outside the loop (e.g. near `Emulations = 1000`).

Comment: Pass the bet as an argument to the function, and have it return the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

One clean way to handle this is to extract your game state into a separate type and make your function a "pure" update that accepts a state variable and returns a new one. You can use a `dataclass` for this:

```
import random
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class GameState:
    money: int = 65
    bet: int = 1
    start_bet: int = 1

def simulate(state: GameState) -> GameState:
    number = random.randint(0,14)
    if(state.money > 0):
        if 8 > number > 0 :
            return GameState(money=state.money+state.bet, 
                             bet=state.start_bet)
        else:
            return GameState(money=state.money-state.bet,
                             bet=state.bet*2)
```

Now you can run this by creating an initial GameState and updating it in your loop:

```
tries = 1000
state = GameState()
for i in range(1000):
    print(f"Iter: {i}, State: {state}")
    state = simulate(state)
    if state is None:
        print("Out of cash!")
        break
```

You can also try it out with different values for starting money and bet by changing the initial `GameState` you create.